# Join 3 tables in postgresql on different objects

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a dataframe with 3 tables, lets call them People, Event, Outcome. The setup for these tables would look like this:

Name has: ID, Name, Age; Outcome has: ID, EventID, EventTime and OutcomeID; Event has: EventID, EventState, EventDate, EventTemp.

I need to run a query that pulls in all the Events that "Sally" competed in and output the EventName, Event Month (extracted from the EventDate), EventTemp, and EventTime. But this issue I'm running into is I need to join Event and Outcome on the EventID and then People and  Outcome on the ID.

Here is what I last tried (which isn't working):

```
SELECT eventname, eventstate, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM eventdate), eventtemp
FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.eventid = O.eventid 
FROM name N JOIN outcome O ON N.id = O.id
WHERE name = "Sally";
```

This is not outputting anything because it throws an error. I am new to postgresql. Can someone help?

Comment: `from` comes prior to `where`

Comment: Updated to add ```where``` after ```from```  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I'm at a rave. There should be only one `from` clause as well with your second one replaced by a comma. Add a tag of `sql` it is a popular tag and someone at a keyboard is sure to answer in short order

Comment: Which fields are in which tables?  `name` is a table, but which field should equal `"Sally"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be one FROM clause, although it can contain multiple JOINs.  I'm assuming that the "name" field is inside the "name" table:

```
SELECT E.eventname, E.eventstate, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM E.eventdate), E.eventtemp
FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.eventid = O.eventid 
             JOIN name N ON N.id = O.id
WHERE N.name = 'Sally';
```

Comment: I think you might need single quotes rather than double for the literal

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Name is in the Name table. This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I was too busy on my high horse correcting the other parts...